# Procedure Alert SQL error

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

When i try execute Job on SQL Agent return error:

> Mensagem SQL Server Scheduled Job 'DBA - Trace Banco de Dados'
>   (0xCEEE34363CF86C41B807EBAE8D2AF05F) - Status: Falha - Invoked on:
>   2018-03-12 12:08:35 - Message: O trabalho falhou.  O trabalho foi
>   invocado por Usuário *********\Administrador. A última etapa a ser
>   executada foi 4 (Cria o Trace).  Foi solicitado que o trabalho
>   iniciasse na etapa 1 (DBA - Desabilita o Trace).

See code:

---

```
USE [Traces]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[stpCreate_Trace]    Script Date: 12/03/2018 11:38:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER  Procedure [dbo].[stpCreate_Trace]
AS
BEGIN
    -- Trace Queries Demoradas
    DECLARE @Id_Alerta_Parametro INT = (SELECT Id_Alerta_Parametro FROM [Traces].[dbo].Alerta_Parametro (NOLOCK) WHERE Nm_Alerta = 'Trace Queries Demoradas')

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Recupera os parametros do Alerta
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DECLARE @Tempo_Traces INT

    SELECT  @Tempo_Traces = Vl_Parametro                    -- Segundos
    FROM [dbo].[Alerta_Parametro]
    WHERE [Id_Alerta_Parametro] = @Id_Alerta_Parametro          -- Trace Queries Demoradas

    -- Trava de segurança para colocar um valor default na variavel
    IF(@Tempo_Traces IS NULL OR @Tempo_Traces < 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Tempo_Traces = 3    -- Segundos
    END 

    -- Create a Queue.
    declare @rc int
    declare @TraceID int
    declare @maxfilesize bigint
    set @maxfilesize = 50

    exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 0, N'C:\Temp\Duracao', @maxfilesize, NULL 

    if (@rc != 0) goto error

    -- Set the events.
    declare @on bit
    set @on = 1

    -- 10 RPC:Completed Ocorre quando uma RPC (chamada de procedimento remoto) é concluída. 
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 1, @on     -- TextData: Valor de texto dependente da classe de evento capturada no rastreamento.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 6, @on     -- NTUserName: Nome de usuário do Microsoft Windows. 
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 8, @on     -- HostName: Nome do computador cliente que originou a solicitação. 
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 10, @on    -- ApplicationName: Nome do aplicativo cliente que criou a conexão com uma instância do SQL Server.
                                                    -- Essa coluna é populada com os valores passados pelo aplicativo e não com o nome exibido do programa.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 11, @on    -- LoginName: Nome de logon do cliente no SQL Server.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 12, @on    -- SPID: ID de processo de servidor atribuída pelo SQL Server ao processo associado ao cliente.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 13, @on    -- Duration: Tempo decorrido (em milhões de segundos) utilizado pelo evento. 
                                                    -- Esta coluna de dados não é populada pelo evento Hash Warning.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 14, @on    -- StartTime: Horário de início do evento, quando disponível.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 15, @on    -- EndTime: Horário em que o evento foi encerrado. Esta coluna não é populada para classes de evento
                                                    -- iniciais, como SQL:BatchStarting ou SP:Starting. Também não é populada pelo evento Hash Warning.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 16, @on    -- Reads: Número de leituras lógicas do disco executadas pelo servidor em nome do evento. 
                                                    -- Esta coluna não é populada pelo evento Lock:Released.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 17, @on    -- Writes: Número de gravações no disco físico executadas pelo servidor em nome do evento.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 18, @on    -- CPU: Tempo da CPU (em milissegundos) usado pelo evento.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 19, @on    -- CPU: Tempo da CPU (em milissegundos) usado pelo evento.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 26, @on    -- ServerName: Nome da instância do SQL Server, servername ou servername\instancename, 
                                                    -- que está sendo rastreada
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 35, @on    -- DatabaseName: Nome do banco de dados especificado na instrução USE banco de dados.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 40, @on    -- DBUserName: Nome de usuário do banco de dados do SQL Server do cliente.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 48, @on    -- RowCounts: Número de linhas no lote.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 64, @on    -- SessionLoginName: O nome de logon do usuário que originou a sessão. Por exemplo, se você 
                                                    -- se conectar ao SQL Server usando Login1 e executar uma instrução como Login2, SessionLoginName
                                                    -- irá exibir Login1, enquanto que LoginName exibirá Login2. Esta coluna de dados exibe logons
                                                    -- tanto do SQL Server, quanto do Windows.

    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 1,  @on    -- TextData: Valor de texto dependente da classe de evento capturada no rastreamento.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 6,  @on    -- NTUserName: Nome de usuário do Microsoft Windows. 
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 8,  @on    -- HostName: Nome do computador cliente que originou a solicitação. 
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 10, @on    -- ApplicationName: Nome do aplicativo cliente que criou a conexão com uma instância do SQL Server. 
                                                    -- Essa coluna é populada com os valores passados pelo aplicativo e não com o nome exibido do programa.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 11, @on    -- LoginName: Nome de logon do cliente no SQL Server.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 12, @on    -- SPID: ID de processo de servidor atribuída pelo SQL Server ao processo associado ao cliente.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 13, @on    -- Duration: Tempo decorrido (em milhões de segundos) utilizado pelo evento. Esta coluna de dados não
                                                    -- é populada pelo evento Hash Warning.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 14, @on    -- StartTime: Horário de início do evento, quando disponível.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 15, @on    -- EndTime: Horário em que o evento foi encerrado. Esta coluna não é populada para classes de evento
                                                    -- iniciais, como SQL:BatchStarting ou SP:Starting. Também não é populada pelo evento Hash Warning.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 16, @on    -- Reads: Número de leituras lógicas do disco executadas pelo servidor em nome do evento. 
                                                    -- Esta coluna não é populada pelo evento Lock:Released.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 17, @on    -- Writes: Número de gravações no disco físico executadas pelo servidor em nome do evento.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 18, @on    -- CPU: Tempo da CPU (em milissegundos) usado pelo evento.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 26, @on    -- ServerName: Nome da instância do SQL Server, servername ou servername\instancename, 
                                                    -- que está sendo rastreada
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 35, @on    -- DatabaseName: Nome do banco de dados especificado na instrução USE banco de dados.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 40, @on    -- DBUserName: Nome de usuário do banco de dados do SQL Server do cliente.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 48, @on    -- RowCounts: Número de linhas no lote.
    exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 64, @on    -- SessionLoginName: O nome de logon do usuário que originou a sessão. Por exemplo, se você se
                                                    -- conectar ao SQL Server usando Login1 e executar uma instrução como Login2, SessionLoginName
                                                    -- irá exibir Login1, enquanto que LoginName exibirá Login2. Esta coluna de dados exibe logons
                                                    -- tanto do SQL Server, quanto do Windows.

    -- Set the Filters.
    declare @intfilter int
    declare @bigintfilter bigint

    exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 7, N'SQL Server Profiler - 4d8f4bca-f08c-4755-b90c-6ec17a6f1275'
    exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 7, N'DatabaseMail90%'

    /*******************************************************************************************************************************
    -- Configura o tempo mínimo para as queries demoradas (em segundos)
    *******************************************************************************************************************************/
    set @bigintfilter = 1000000 * @Tempo_Traces     --  @Tempo_Traces (em segundos)

    exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 13, 0, 4, @bigintfilter

    set @bigintfilter = null
    exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 13, 0, 1, @bigintfilter

    exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 0, 7, N'NO STATS%'

    exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 1, 0, 7, N'NULL%'

    -- Set the trace status to start.
    exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1

    -- Display trace id for future references.
    select TraceID = @TraceID

    goto finish

    error: 
        select ErrorCode = @rc

    finish: 
END
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It would also help if you translated the error message

Comment: Mensagem SQL Server Scheduled Job 'DBA - Trace Banco de Dados' (0xCEEE34363CF86C41B807EBAE8D2AF05F) - 
Status: Fail - Invoked on: 2018-03-12 12:08:35 - Message: Work Fail. 
The work Invoked on Usuário *********\Administrador. 
The last step to be execute 4 (Cria o Trace "Create Trace").
 
It was requested that the work begin in step 1 (DBA - Desabilita o Trace "DBA - Disable trace").

Comment: You need to look at the Agent's history for this Job and see what the actual error message was.  Also, questions like this are really more DBA than programming questions and would probably be better asked at http://dba.stackexchange.com